# Congratulations robjohn for getting into the 100k club.

Tags: discussion, specific-user, celebration

We truly appreciate your constant presence and insightful hints in the Mathematics chat room.

Your dedication to learning is inspiring.

Thank you also, for all your hard work as a moderator.

[image: $-(mean)^2$]

Comment: Congrats robjohn.  Your clear explanations of even the most difficult problems are an inspiration for us all.

Comment: Congratulations, robjohn!

Comment: and thanks for [$\LaTeX$ support for chat](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297)...

Comment: yes this is a useful and friendly site which is due in no small part to the actions of users such as robjohn

Comment: Congratulations robjohn, your answers and your avatar are awesome!

Comment: Kudos, robjohn, for surpassing $100$K, *while at the same time* serving as a moderator through thick and thin!

Comment: Congratulations on consistently nice answers.

Comment: @robjohn The presence of people like you on this site keeps me going in my quest to self-learn mathematics. Thank you, and congratulations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks, robjohn

... for moderation

... for [2500++ answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn?tab=answers)

... and [1 question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77607/how-to-sum-this-series-for-pi-2-directly)

Comment: Nice answer :-)

Comment: 5 questions* (updated october 2020)